# Does a static variable have a separate instance for each client in action script flex?

Tags: variables, apache-flex, static

I have a declared a static variable in action script which gets updated by the value which client provides. My doubt is whether the static variable will be shared amongst all the users of that client application or will the static variable have a different instance for each client(browser window)?

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is unique per Flash player instance. So if a user opens the same page with your .swf embedded in the page multiple times (in multiple different browsers or in multiple tabs in the same browser), the static variable will exist as a separate value in all those different Flash Player instances. (One Flash Player per browser and/or per tab.)

This means that a static variable will not be shared among multiple independent Flash Player instances. If you need to synchronize the value of the static variable, you'll have to talk to those other Flash Players or prevent the user from opening the same .swf multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

static variable is shared between **multiple class instances** in the same application instance, not between **multiple application instances**.

if you want to share some object between many application instances switch the application type do this :

1- a web application:  use a server application that communicate the same value to multiple clients (swf instances).

2- Desktop application : a shared file or a third party desktop running application,...